# How to subscribe IBM Watson IOT Platform with CC3220s launchpad and Code Composer Studio?

Tags: iot, ibm-watson, texas-instruments, watson-iot

I have been trying to send messages to IBM IOT Platform using CC3220s Launchpad and Code Composer Studio cc32xx SDK, watson_mqttclient_CC3220S_Launchxl_tirtos_ccs project.

---

I can send the messages to quickstart broker.
However, I got:

- ***Invalid userID () for device auth:

  ClientID='d:u45vsd:ti-simplelink:9884e34e0611',

  ClientIP=178.241.108.68***
  Connection Log Message on IBM Watson IOT Platform
- ***CONNACK:

  Connection Error: 5

  Connection to broker failed, Error code: -5

  BRIDGE DISCONNECTION***
  Error on CCS serial terminal

---

I have done following changes on CCS mqttclient code and IBM Watson IOT Platform:

1. I have changed the security level as "TLS Optional" on the security options IBM Watson IOT Platform and I have added new device with following informations:

   > Organization ID       : u45vsd
   >   Device Type       : ti-simplelink
   >   Device ID     : 9884e34e0611
   >   Authentication Method : use-token-auth
   >   Authentication Token  : zzzzzzzzzzzzz
2. Following codes were changed in network_if.h:

   > define SSID_NAME               "Netmaster EB75-G"
   >   define SECURITY_KEY             "*password*"
   >   define SECURITY_TYPE           SL_WLAN_SEC_TYPE_WPA_WPA2
3. Following codes were changed in mqtt_client_app.c:

   > define SERVER_ADDRESS       "u45vsd.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com"
   >   char ClientId[64] = "d:u45vsd:ti-simplelink:9884e34e0611";
   >   const char *ClientUsername = "use-token-auth";
   >   const char *ClientPassword = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
   >   sprintf(ClientId, "d:u45vsd:ti-simplelink:%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
   >            macAddress[0], macAddress[1], macAddress[2],
   >            macAddress[3], macAddress[4], macAddress[5]);

---

What am I missing?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how does the connection method looks like in mqtt_client_app.c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem with uncomment lines below:

```
#define CLNT_USR_PWD
#define SUBSCRIBE
```

BR,